# I want to change my laravel database query to model relationship query for search data from database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am learning laravel Eloquent relationship, I successfully created a relationship between models for eq city belongsTo State and belongsTo country.

```
public function state(){

    return $this->belongsTo(State::class,'state_id', 'sr_id');
}

public function country(){

    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class,'country_id', 'sr_id');
}
```

this is my old search code, I want to know how we search data using model relationship method, how  we call each columns from their following table.

```
$city = city::leftjoin('master_country','master_country.sr_id','=','master_city.country_id')
         ->leftjoin('master_state','master_state.sr_id','=','master_city.state_id')
         ->where('master_city.sr_status',0)
         ->where('master_city.sr_id','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
         ->orWhere('master_city.sr_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
         ->orWhere('master_city.city_tel_code','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
         ->orWhere('master_country.sr_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
         ->orWhere('master_state.sr_name','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
         ->orderBy('master_city.sr_id')
         ->paginate(3,array('master_city.*','master_country.sr_name AS c_name','master_state.sr_name As s_name'));
```

so it would we like..

```
City::with('state','country')->where etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```php
$cities = City::with(
    [
        'state' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('state_column', 'some_value');
        },
        'country' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('country_column', 'some_value');
        }
    ]
)->get();
```

If you don't want to retrieve the relation data, you can use the `whereHas()` method:

```php
City::whereHas('state', fn (Builder $builder) => $builder->where('state_column', 'some_value')));
```

Using arrow function is not required.

[More documentation on this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)